# Why in laminar flow velocity of layers keep on increasing as distance from fixed layer increases?

Tags: forces, fluid-dynamics, kinetic-theory, viscosity

A text says "when a liquid flows over a fixed surface, the layer of molecules in the immediate contact of surface is stationary. The velocity of upper layers increases as the distance of layers from the fixed layer increases ".

Can someone explain qualitatively in terms of molecular forces and molecular movement why the velocity increases as distance from fixed layer increases? I can understand that layer in contact with solid surface is stationary according to the no slip condition.

Comment: See Physical Justification in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No-slip_condition

Comment: So it means as adhesion dominates cohesion hence due to force imbalance net velocity is zero for outer layer and the force is equal and opposite for other layers ?

Comment: If you understand why the velocity decreases as you move towards the surface, why are you having difficulty with the reversed situation? How the velocity changes as you move towards the surface is described by a diffusional process akin to Fick's law.

Comment: @nluigi No I dont understand why the velocity decreases I wrote that I only understand why the layer in contact with wall is stationary. What is Ficks law?

Comment: @nluigi Can you please explain the diffusional process or give some link for it ?